# Text not in center of Line Height

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center two spans horizontally in a 150px div. I thought the simplest way of doing this world be to set the line-height of each of the spans to 150px, but for some reason, the text is not being centered when I try this method.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/shipping/images/TV.png" />
    <span class="cantstop">CAN'T STOP</span> <span class="shipping">Shipping</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top {
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.top img {
    max-height: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.cantstop {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 150px;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: auto 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px rgba(129,93,150,0.5);
    }

.shipping {
    font-family: 'Grand Hotel', cursive;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 75px;
    line-height: 150px;
    margin: auto 0;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 0px rgba(217,144,178,1);
    }
```

You can see the issue in action at cantstopshipping.com

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
.top img {
    float:left;
}

.top span {
    float:left;
}
```

and change

```
.cantstop,
.shipping {
    line-height:130px;
}
```

The top container is actually 130px not 150px due to the padding on the top and bottom.

Hope my answer makes sense, let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To align it vertically,

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/p2yR8/)

Use `vertical-align:middle`

```
.top span {
  vertical-align:middle
}
```

---

To align it horizontally,

[**DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/zaVSV/)

Use `.top { text-align:center }`

Comment: I applied that code (and left the green borders) but for some reason, it not aligning in the center.